# Regex for parsing name and email from a single string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse name and email address from a string of type 
**Ansh Aryan <ansharyan@mailinator.com>**
Need a regex to be used in javascript for this purpose so that i get

 name= Ansh Aryan

email = ansharyan@mailinator.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/([^<]+)\s<(.*)>/
```

Of course, if some deviation from that pattern should be allowed, you'll have to tweak it to reflect it, but if not then it'll be fine.

Some brief explanation of the regex:

- `([^<]+)`: Match and capture anything until a `<` symbol is found.
- `\s`: Match but don't capture a single space token, which could be a space, a tab, or whatever.
- `<(.*)>`: Match the `<...>` and capture what is inside it.

This will yield an array of `matches`, where `matches[0]` should be all the input, `matches[1]` the name, and `matches[2]` the email you are looking for.

Comment: Just a little improvement: ```/(.*[^\s*<])?\s*<(.*)>/```; allows for cases such as: Test <a@b.com>, Test<a@b.com>, <a@b.com>, etc.